# Realm Swift Results get object at index

Tags: swift, realm

I couldn't find this anywhere so I thought I'd ask here.

I'm using Realm in Swift and I'm having trouble to get an object out of the `Results` at a certain index. I'm using it inside my `UITableViewController`. I'm making a var at the beginning of the class:

```
var tasks:Results<Task>?
```

And then to get it I `.objects(type: T.Type)`:

```
tasks = realm.objects(Task)
```

I was hoping to be able to do something like this:

```
let task = tasks!.objectAtIndex(1)
```

Is this a limitation or is there another way to do this?

Comment: Does `let task = tasks![1]` work?

Comment: @vacawama I feel so dumb... Didn't realize it was an `Array`. Thanks! If you write it as an answer I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use standard indexing syntax to retrieve the value:

```
let task = tasks![1]
```

Since `tasks` is an optional, it could be `nil`.  A safer way to write this would be to use *optional binding* with *optional chaining*:

```
if let task = tasks?[1] {
    // use task
}
```